# Fuse overlapping mesh from a bevel curve

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a bezier-curve with a bevel- and a taper object which makes a nice rod-like shape. But if I make too sharpe turn of the original curve I get an annoying overlap of the mesh which generates "folds" on the inside of the object. Does Blender have a nice function or modifier or something which will try to fuse (and maybe smooth) the mesh along one of these overlapping lines?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately curves don't support Boolean modifiers... You can use a remesh modifier but the polycount will explode and the shading will suffer. Or convert to a mesh and use a boolean set to union with a dummy object and check "self" so the object intersects with itself. but the topology will be horrendous :)

Comment: I'm fine with converting to mesh. But I need a simple "one-click" algorithm. It won't do to use boolean modifiers of manually delete vertices.